# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "where": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am getting`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "where": syntax error (code 1):` exception in the below code..Where i am going wrong?

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_VIDEO + " order by " + KEY_TIMESTAMP + " ASC "+"where " + KEY_TYPE + "='trending'";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ORDER BY` must be the **last** SQL clause in your query.
So, it must come **after** the WHERE condition.

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: What you are saying here is technically untrue as `LIMIT` comes after `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Yep, true. I wasn't considering that. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` must come after `WHERE` in the `SELECT` statement.

See [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

may be the:

```
/*code*/+ " ASC "+"where "+ /*morecode*/
```

try:

```
 /*code*/+ " ASC WHERE "+ /*morecode*/
```

Comment: What does it change? The result would be the same: `ASC WHERE`. Only the execution speed will be `faster` (about 0.001 nanosecond?) in the second case, because of **one less string concatenation**.

Comment: you are right, but i just want to help, nothing more, see ya

Comment: Well, you did **not**, sorry.

Comment: Really, this post provides **no answer** at all.